# How to implement local DB + external API sources in Kiba

Tags: kiba-etl

I'm trying to implement the following ETL job in [Kiba](https://www.kiba-etl.org/), in the context of a Rails app:

- For a given local database record
- [Search](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/search.php) its name using a remote application API (Evernote)
- For each record found with the API, get the GUIDs of all the tags used on this record and consolidate this in a single array
- Using the same API, [retrieve](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listTags) the full list of tags used, in order to get their labels from the GUID
- Process these tags (keep, ignore, replace) based on internal business logic
- Save these tags on the local database record

My question is: *how would you model the **sources** in this example?*

The starting point is the local database record, but the real data comes from two calls to the API (1/ records returned by the search and 2/ full tags list).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can modelize it that way: assuming you get the list of ids of database records in some variable (e.g. `people_ids`), you can have something like as a first iteration:

```rb
Kiba.parse do
  source Kiba::Common::Sources::Enumerable, -> { people_ids }

  transform do |person_id|
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      # here some HTTP query for search, retrieval of tags etc, and 
      # you would yield each result in a loop
      y << {person_id: person_id, tags: [...] }
    end
  end

  transform Kiba::Common::Transforms::EnumerableExploder
  # SNIP
end
```

As for the tags, if they are already in your database and in small volumes, you would load them early on to construct some form of lookup table:

```rb
tags = {}
Kiba.parse do
  pre_process do
    # here preload the tags & data required to decide on your business logic
  end
  # SNIP
end
```

This way you can associate later in the pipeline each incoming tag, with the proper tag id in your database, and simply use `ActiveRecord` to insert the relation.

Alternatively, if you want an already built solution for fast inserts/upserts with vendor support by us, you can also leverage [Kiba Pro](https://github.com/thbar/kiba/wiki#kiba-pro), hence supporting the development of the Open-Source version too!

Hope this properly answers your question, feel free to comment more otherwise!